# Django - Accessing Images from Foreign Key Field

Tags: django, django-models, model

Im trying to make a seperate Image model to save all of my pictures for the Articles model.
I have created the Image Model with the foreign key to my Article model.

After doing that, I am stuck, I'm trying to get the pictures for each article to render for the relevant article, but I'm not making any progress. Anyone with a few spare minutes to help ?

Thank you !!!

my view:

```
class ArticlesView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'
    template_name = 'news/articles.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticlesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        category_pk = self.request.GET.get('pk', None)
        if category_pk:
            return Article.objects.filter(article_category__pk=category_pk).order_by("-pub_date")
        return Article.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
```

my models :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=200, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', default="",
                         always_update=True, unique=True)
    author = models.CharField('Author', max_length=200, default="")
    description = models.TextField('Description', default="")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    article_text = models.TextField('Article text', default="")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    article_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete="models.CASCADE", default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ArticleImages(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete="models.CASCADE", related_name="Images")
    image = models.ImageField("Image")
```

Thank you stack !!

Comment: You use `{{ article.article_image.url }}` inside your template, but your model `Article` does not have any field called `article_image`. The current `related_name` from images to article is `Images` + it is a OneToMany-relation, so in your template you would have to iterate over the images to show them as you can have more than just one.

Comment: My bad, I just changed the models, my original Article field had 6 image models, and then I decided to make an image model, that's why you see the old fields. The template actually isnt important at all, I'm just trying to figure out how to grab the images from the Image model and include them in my templates. I will remove the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the ArticleImage's `related_name` as 'Images', but you try to access that relation through `article.article_image` in your template. The correct way to access the Article images is through `article.Images.image`

However, because you specified the relation of image as a ForeignKey, an ArticleImage can have only one Article, but one Article can have multiple images. (a so called many-to-one relationship). You should change the ForeignKey in ArticleImage to a `OneToOneField`. 
But, since the ArticleImage is a OneToOne relation to Article, why not set an `image` field directly on the article?

Furthermore, you should not capitalise the related_name `'Images'`, and if it's a one-to-one-field, consider changing it to a singular `'image'`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not following..an article image can have only one article, but one article can have multiple images...that is exactly what I want no ?
The thing is, lets say my Article has 6 pictures. I put them in via the Image model, and after that I need the 6 images to render on their spots in my template. Im not sure how to get the images from 1 - 6. I know they have a id, and they all share the same article_id in the database. Should I get them by id ?  That is where I get lost.
I can get them via the for loop, but wouldnt that just get all the images and render them all at once ?

Comment: @Sandi did you ever reach a conclusion on this?